# Counting number of messages sent by sendmail

Tags: sendmail, linux

Does anyone know of a utility of that would give me the total number of email messages sent by sendmail, using old maillogs ?

Someone suggested the use of the mailstats utility, however this program seems to give the statistical information for all mail log file entries. Though this is beneficial, it's not helpful on this case since a single mail message sent by sendmail can log anywhere to 5 different log entries.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `grep -c` to count the number of matching lines instead of pipe `grep` to `wc -l`:

```
grep -c "Message accepted for delivery" /var/log/maillog
```

Comment: Neat trick! It's much faster than piping! On a 2GB file it ran in 1/3 the time.

Answer (score 4):

Does `grep 'Message accepted for delivery' /var/log/maillog| wc -l` provide the number you need?

Comment: Is the string 'Message accepted for delivery' the standard sendmail log entry for successful messages? If so then this is what I was looking for. -Tony